# permutation test on correlation coefficient

Tags: hypothesis-testing, permutation-test, hierarchical-clustering

I have a correlation coefficient of two hierarchical clustering trees with 20 labels.

I want to check the hypothesis that the labels of the trees are uncorrelated with a permutation test.

I calculated a p-value using 500 permutations

```
obsereved.coeff = 0.292

sample.permut <- c()
n <- 500

for(i in 1:n){
  t = tree2 %>% dist(method = "euclidean") %>% hclust("complete") %>% as.dendrogram %>% set("labels",permute(row.names(tree2)))
  sample.permut[i] = cor_bakers_gamma(tree1, t)
}
p-val = sum(abs(sample.permut)>=obsereved.coeff)/500
# p-value:  0.002
```

- are 500 permutations enough?
- is my p-value calculation correct?
- can I conclude that the labels of the two trees are related, with a 5% probability that the null is correct?

[image]

Comment: Unrelated or uncorrelated? There's a difference.

Comment: uncorrelated. both trees have the same 20 labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are 500 permutations enough?

Never write simulation code with `500` in it. Always write `n <- 500` and use `n` for the rest. Then as your last step try increasing `n` to higher values. Only if that does not change the result in relevant ways assume that `n` was large enough. Or run it with `n <-500` many times and see if the results are stable enough.

> is my p-value calculation correct?

boils down as to whether everything is correct with
`p-val = sum(abs(sample.permut)>=obsereved.coeff)/500`
As we do not know what `sample.permut` is and have not seen the rest of the code, we could not honestly say "yes, that is correct". Btw, have you considered one-tailed vs two-tailed testing?

> with a 5% probability that the null is correct?

No. That is not what a $p$-value is.

Comment: sample.permut is a vector of correlations between tree1 and tree2 with permuted labels

Comment: "Never write simulation code with `500` in it. Always write `n <- 500` and use n for the rest." I second this advice.

Comment: In bootstrapping it's often enough to re-sample 2000 times. With permutation tests where I know the answer from other methods, I have often found there is improvement up to about 100,000 iterations (and the extra running time is seldom an issue).